# Error attaching User on Kaa C++

Tags: c++, kaa

I'm currently try to build an application which is sending messages to other endpoints, but I'm getting the following errors when I try to attach an user.

[c**lient_1][2017-Feb-12 15:26:18.074820][0x76446450][warning][DefaultOperationTcpChannel.cpp:104]: Channel [default_operation_kaa_tcp_channel] failed server authentication: Connection Refused: verification failed
[client_1][2017-Feb-12 15:26:18.076020][0x76446450][warning][DefaultOperationTcpChannel.cpp:331]:   Channel [default_operation_kaa_tcp_channel] detected 'ENDPOINT_NOT_REGISTERED' failover for TransportConnectionInfo{ server: 'OPERATIONS', protocol: 'TransportProtocolId{ id: 0x56c8ff92, version: 1 }', accessPointId: -1835393002, isFailed: 'false' }
[client_1][2017-Feb-12 15:26:18.076691][0x76446450][warning][BootstrapManager.cpp:80]:  Attempt to reconnect to current Operations service will be made in 5 seconds**

I'm calling function attach user, the same way as the examples

```
kaaClient->attachUser(KAA_USER_ID, KAA_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN, std::make_shared<UserAttachCallback>(*kaaClient));
```

I'm using the latest kaa version and running on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Raspberry Pi cannot connect to the Kaa Sandbox.

Please check that the Kaa host on the Management page of your Kaa Sandbox web interface is configured to the correct IP address of the PC host it is running on and that the Raspberry Pi can reach the Kaa Sandbox via that IP address. The default setting there is 'localhost' which works well for locally running applications, but needs to be changed for remote access.

Please also make sure the Kaa SDK for all the applications is re-taken after the Kaa host setting change and all the applications are re-built with that Kaa SDK version.

The Kaa operations service IP address is embedded into the Kaa SDK, that is why you should always download the Kaa SDK again and re-build the application should the Kaa IP address change.

See [Kaa Networking documentation](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Getting-started/#networking) for more details.